Having an issue with Visual Studio logins for Visual Studio Pro 2022... It just keeps spinning
So, in Visual Studio Pro 2022 If I try to login to my account to activate the license it just keeps spinning and never signs me in.
I have already tried all 3 of the login settings in the Visual Studio Options. Neither have worked. I am behind a proxy, but have whitelisted everything that Microsoft suggests (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2022).
Have also tried reinstalling and on a different computer with the same issue.
It has to be something being blocked. But I am having difficulty with narrowing it down. If anyone has had similar issues and found a solution, would be glad to hear about it.

It is a holiday in the USA today, Microsoft servers notoriously stop working on such days.  Try again tomorrow.

You can run devenv /Log ActivityLog.xml to collect the login event and check what it says.

@HansPassant the issue has been going on for a while

Did you see any error message during sign in ?
Please run devenv /Log ActivityLog.xmland sign in VS again then check the generated activity log to see what it says.You can type keyword "sign in" to search log.
By default, the log file is located here:%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<Version>\ActivityLog.xml
Besides, common suggestions to troubleshoot:
1.Switch to another existing MS account and to see if you can sign in. If it works ,the issue is account level otherwise network/machine level.
2.Delete all files of %localappdata%.Identityservice.
3.Disable installed extension or antivirus which may block VS and reboot your machine then run VS as administrator.
4 .If it is a network related issue, i would suggest you follow this guide to get support.

ok, thanks ill take a look

If you find any error message related sign in, feel free to let me know.

I did not find anything sadly. I just can't figure it out and the issue is that soon our devs are going to be in trouble because they wont be able to sign in to renew their license. Is there any other logging i can look at? It is just so weird that it just keeps spinning and never logs in nor errors out.,

You issue is similar to this one.If the issue persists, i would suggest you to contact VS Subscription Team to get assistance.
